# Are there any MIDP 3.0 based devices?

Tags: java-me, midp

It's been while for release of MIDP 3.0 spec. But is there any device which supports this specifications ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there are any commercially-available MIDP 3.0 phones available yet. The [Java ME benchmark list](http://www.club-java.com/TastePhone/J2ME/MIDP_Benchmark.jsp) only shows MIDP 2.1 as the highest supported version. Even Motorola, the spec lead, does not [list any MIDP 3.0 phones](http://developer.motorola.com/platforms/java/), nor does [Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/?filter=all).

Answer (score 2):

Samsung galaxy pro b7510 support MIDP 3.0.Refer the link

[Midp3.0 supported device](http://www.newcellphoneprices.com/filter_view.php?filter_type=java&filter=3&txt=MIDP%203.0)

Some of **android** phones support **MIDP 3.0**

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this Android support?

Comment: What "Daniel Monteiro". I cannot get your words.

Comment: "Some of android phones support MIDP 3.0" - can you please show me one that does?